# Vue / Volar extension in Visual Studio Code keeps crashing: The JS/TS language service immediately crashed 5 times…

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vscode-extensions, volar

I just wasted a day on this, so I thought I would get it down incase anyone else is experiencing it.

Opened a `vue` 3 project and got the following error:

> The JS/TS language service immediately crashed 5 times. The service
> will not be restarted....

And then it listed a bunch of possible extensions that might be causing it - one of which is `Vue.volar`.

Disabling the `Vue - Official` extension does stop the crash, but then we have no `vue`  or `TypeScript` language services in VS Code.

I narrowed it down to destructuring objects in HTML attributes in a `vue` template:

```js
 <RouterView v-slot="{Component}">
   <Transition name="fade" appear>
     <component :is="Component" />
   </Transition>
 </RouterView>
```

If you change that to

```js
 <RouterView v-slot="props">
   <Transition name="fade" appear>
     <component :is="props.Component" />
   </Transition>
 </RouterView>
```

Its fine - but a workaround....

Comment: did you post a bug report about it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out the issue started in the `2.0` release of `Vue - Official`

You can roll `Vue - Official` back to older versions.

- Search for `Vue - Official` in the VS Code extensions panel.
- Hit the cog icon
- choose `Install another version...`

For me, the earliest working build was `1.8.27`

Comment: Thank you! If you should ever need a new kidney I will give you mine

Comment: ha!  Sounds like you had the same pain as me then!  Glad it helped

Comment: However, there is no option to install previous version using UI/cog icon so I installed with command line `code --install-extension vue.volar@1.8.27`

Comment: You should also restart VSCode. A detail, but an important one :D

Answer (score 5):

Install previous version using command line

```
code --install-extension vue.volar@1.8.27
```